# How to implement excel's array formula feature using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a formula in excel sheet that has the following format

```
{=SUM(IF(C3:C65536=F11,B3:B65536))}
```

its a formula array. How do I implement this in Java using Apache POI API?

## I did this in java

```
cell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
cell.setCellFormula("SUM(IF(C3:C65536=F"+totalCtr+",B3:B65536))");
```

where totalCtr is an int variable that iterates from 0... n 
and is part of "F" in the formula. So I can go from one cell to the next.

Comment: did you just try to insert it as a formula as-is? like `cell.setCellFormula("{=SUM(IF(C3:C65536=F11,B3:B65536))}");`

Comment: nope I removed the equals part and curly bracket because you're not supposed to include it in setcellformula.

Comment: Well I just saw, that http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/formula.html says, it isnt supported yet.

Answer (score 4):

The newer Version of POI supports array formulas

see https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/formula.html

```
 Array Formulas: via Sheet.setArrayFormula() and Sheet.removeArrayFormula()
```